# Python: functools.partial returns error

Tags: python, partial, functools

I am encountering a problem using `functools.partial`.

**My code:**

```
selected_words = ['awesome', 'great', 'fantastic', 'amazing', 'love', 'horrible', 'bad', 'terrible', 'awful', 'wow', 'hate']

def awsome_count(x,i):
    if selected_words[i] in x:
        y=1
    else:
        y=0
    return y

partialfun=functools.partial(awsome_count,0)

partialfun(products[2]['word_count'])
```

`products` is a SFrame.

**Error:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-e51348a5d1f0> in <module>()
----> 1 partialfun(products[2]['word_count'])

<ipython-input-66-9ba8c7128add> in awsome_count(x, i)
      1 def awsome_count(x,i):
----> 2     if selected_words[i] in x:
      3         y=1
      4     else:
      5         y=0

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

I am using `partial` function, is because I want to use `apply` function:

```
products['word_count'].apply(functools.partial(awsome_count,0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave your `partial()` object one *positional* argument:

```
functools.partial(awsome_count, 0)
```

That argument is applied **first**; additional positional arguments are added to that one, so your call:

```
partialfun(products[2]['word_count'])
```

becomes:

```
awesome_count(0, products[2]['word_count'])
```

which is the *wrong order* for your function.

If you want to apply a default value for the `i` argument of your function, use a keyword argument instead of a positional argument:

```
partialfun = functools.partial(awsome_count, i=0)
```

Now the call `partialfun(products[2]['word_count'])` becomes

```
awsome_count(products[2]['word_count'], i=0)
```

Comment: Hey, the answer definitely helpful. I voted up just now, not sure whether I incorrectly vote just now. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, it can't have been you as you can't downvote until you have 125 points or more. :-)